# SEO - Better empty title tag or skip title tag?

Tags: html, seo

What is better, if somebody skip `<title>` tag or `<meta name="description" />`

or leave empty value:

```
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
```

? Or maybe all above has the same meaning for crawlers?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to leave the title tag and description meta tag out than to have them populated with empty strings.

**Best:**

Unique, keyword-rich title tag and relevant description meta tag.

**Okay:**

Unique, keyword-rich title tag and **no** description meta tag.

**Bad:**

No title tag and no description meta tag.

**Very bad:**

Empty title tag and description meta tag.

**Worst:**

Same title and description meta-tag on each page

Comment: Having no title tag would result in invalid html.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't automatically kill you in search. Google will grab info from the ODP, or from the keywords used to link to you to decide what to show. I remember a few years back when nike.com redirected to a huge Flash site and had no tags at all. It was shocking and invalid, but it didn't stop Google from putting them in the top spot.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your `<title>` tag is almost certainly the most important on page SEO factor. Leaving it blank is essentially SEO suicide. Not coincidentally, it is also very bad usability as users use it to tell what page they are on and it is also the default title used when a page is bookmarked.

An empty meta description isn't a big deal. It isn't used for ranking purposes and its content may be used as a page's description in the search results. However, if it is blank other content can be used as a page's description so leaving it blank won't actually harm your rankings.

Answer (score 0):

It is required to have the title tag in your html document. If you don't have a description for your page then don't put the meta element in your document.

I don't see how this is SEO if you don't want to have a title or description in your html.